# Do we still need to use the remote command to setup github push ssh access?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

Do we still need to do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repository.git
```

After cloning the repository in order to access it via ssh?  I could have sworn it was automatic before.  Here's what I did.

1) Deleted my ssh key from github just to make sure the one I have is current.

2) Added the [key back to github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

3) [Cloned my repository - git@github.com:superflycss/cli.git](https://github.com/superflycss/cli)

4) Made some updates, committed, and pushed.

It's still asking me for my username and password?

Comment: `git clone` automatically sets up a remote called `origin` pointed at the URL from which you cloned. What makes you think that doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my question with all my steps

Comment: If you were missing your `origin` remote `push`ing wouldn't get far enough to ask for a username and password (assuming you don't have other remotes). That's not the problem. When you say "cloned my repository", do you actually own that repo? Are you sure you cloned via SSH and not via HTTPS? What is the _exact_ output that you're seeing?

Comment: Yes - The repo is in my organization (I created the organization) and I'm using the SSH url - git@github.com:superflycss/cli.git

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the [ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) step:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

The ssh-agent step is mandatory only if your private ssh key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) is passphrase protected.

And considering git was falling back directly to asking your *username* and password, that might indicate your private key was *not* passphrase protected.
If it was asking first for a passphrase, then yes, the ssh-agent will help cache said passphrase.

Comment: Strange because it's not password protected.  I just ran ssh-agent as indicated and it started working.  I never entered a password.

Comment: My understanding from before (As you are indicating), and hence the reason why I'm confused, is that the purpose of the ssh-agent is to cache password ...

Comment: @Ole I believe its purpose is to cache the *passphrase* (not password, which is associated to a username account) of a SSH private key. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent)

Comment: right - I meant what you just said :).  So I was expecting it to work because I have a passphraseless key ... but it did not work at first.  Only after I started the SSH agent.  Github seems to indicate that it has to be started regardless, as they have another guide for using keys with passphrases?

Comment: @Ole I never needed to use an ssh-agent for a passphraseless key. Maybe the public key is not properly registered, and it defaults to username/*password*? What does `ssh -T git@github.com` returns?